# Como saber o numero do índice em um array multidimensional?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, array

Informações:
Salas: 25;
Professores: 4;
Q02, Q03, Q04: Um aluno de uma sala classificou de 0 a 10 o professor. A partir desses números, foi gerada uma media.

Existe um select com a lista de professores, e quando um é selecionado, preciso exibir TODAS as salas que o mesmo da aula (feito), a posição dele (dentre os quatro professores) com base na média (NAQUELA MESMA SALA), isso para Q02, Q03 e Q04. Também existe uma media GERAL de conceito, que será feito não só com os professores que dão aula naquela turma, mas sim todos os professores de todas as salas.

> **EXPLICAÇÃO DO ARRAY**

[image: explicacao]

> **RESULTADO ESPERADO**

[image: array de dados]

> **AMOSTRA DOS DADOS DO BANCO**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **SCRIPT:**

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
$nomeProfessor = (isset($_POST['frmProfessor'])) ? addslashes($_POST['frmProfessor']) : 'ABNER';

//LISTA TODOS OS PROFESSORES
$listaProfessor = new Read;
$listaProfessor->FullRead("SELECT Nome FROM ang_relatorio GROUP BY Nome");

//LISTA TODAS AS SALAS DO PROFESSOR
$listaSalaProfessor = new Read;
$listaSalaProfessor->FullRead("SELECT Sala, Nome FROM ang_relatorio WHERE Nome=:professor GROUP BY Sala", "professor={$nomeProfessor}");

//LISTA TODAS AS SALAS
$todasSalas = new Read;
$todasSalas->FullRead("SELECT Sala FROM ang_relatorio GROUP BY Sala");

$media = new Read;
//SELECIONA A MEDIA DO PROFESSOR EM UMA SALA E ARMAZENA EM UM ARRAY
foreach ($listaSalaProfessor->getResult() as $key => $sala):
    extract($sala);
    $media->FullRead('SELECT (AVG(Q02) + AVG(Q03) + AVG(Q04)) / 3 FROM ang_relatorio WHERE Nome=:professor AND Sala=:sala', "professor={$nomeProfessor}&sala={$Sala}");
    $mediaProfessorSala[] = $media->getResult();
endforeach;

foreach ($todasSalas->getResult() as $key => $sala):
    extract($sala);
    $selecionaSala = new Read;
    $selecionaSala->FullRead("SELECT Nome, Sala, (AVG(Q02) + AVG(Q03) + AVG(Q04)) / 3 FROM ang_relatorio WHERE Sala=:sala GROUP BY Nome ORDER BY (AVG(Q02) + AVG(Q03) + AVG(Q04)) / 3 DESC", "sala={$Sala}");
    $professoresSala[] = $selecionaSala->getResult();
endforeach;

//RETORNA O CONCEITO DO PROFESSOR REFERENTE AOS OUTROS
function Conceito($posicao) {
    if ($posicao <= 7):
        return 'C';
    elseif ($posicao >= 8 && $posicao <= 14):
        return 'B';
    elseif ($posicao >= 15 && $posicao <= 21):
        return 'A';
    else:
        return 'Posição incorreta.';
    endif;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Relatórios</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= URL; ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= URL; ?>/assets/css/awesome.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= URL; ?>/assets/css/estilo.css"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <form method="POST">
                <select name="frmProfessor" class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($listaProfessor->getResult() as $key => $professor):
                        extract($professor);
                        $selected = ($Nome == $nomeProfessor) ? 'selected' : '';
                        echo "<option value='{$Nome}' $selected>{$Nome}</option>";
                    endforeach;
                    ?>
                </select>
            </form>

            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>#SALA</th>
                    <th>#Q02</th>
                    <th>#Q03</th>
                    <th>#Q04</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>SALA</td>
                    <td>POSIÇÃO DO PROFESSOR REFERENTE AOS OUTROS COM BASE NA MEDIA DE Q02</td>
                    <td>POSIÇÃO DO PROFESSOR REFERENTE AOS OUTROS COM BASE NA MEDIA DE Q03</td>
                    <td>POSIÇÃO DO PROFESSOR REFERENTE AOS OUTROS COM BASE NA MEDIA DE Q04</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```